# Efficient Resampling time series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, pandas-resample

I have been working on time-series data resampling using Pandas. It works well and give required results. However, the performance is little slow as per my current requirement.

**Problem**: I have minute data that I need to resample to many frequencies such as `5min, 15min, 3H`. Pandas resampling works fine when the dataset is small but if I want to resample large number of records (10 days data of 1000 symbols) it's performance decreases significantly.

**Tried**:

1. I have tried to implement resampling in `numpy` arrays but it is even slower (see below). (Probably due to how I implemented it).
2. Use `apply` with `resample` method in `pandas` and use a custom function in `cython` (new for me btw) for aggregation. Performance was below when `resample` and `agg` are used.
3. Similarly to #2, experimented with `numba.jit`, but no improvement.
4. Split data and used `multiprocessing` for sampling. It improves the performance by ~50% but overhead and compute requirements increase significantly.

Here is the sample code I used for checking:

Observations:

1. When I remove `sum` in `agg` for `pandas`, the performance improves a little (~15%).
2. Numpy is way slower than expected

```py
from datetime import datetime
from time import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

symbols = 1000
start = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2023, 1, 2)
data_cols = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
agg_props = {'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last', 'volume': 'sum'}
base, sample = '1min', '5min'


def pandas_resample(df: pd.DataFrame):
    df.sort_values(['sid', 'timestamp'], inplace=True)
    df = df.set_index('timestamp')
    re_df = df.groupby('sid').resample(sample, label='left', closed='left').agg(agg_props).reset_index()
    return re_df


def numpy_resample(arr):
    intervals = pd.date_range(arr[:, 1].min(), arr[:, 1].max(), freq=sample)
    intervals = list(zip(intervals[:-1], intervals[1:]))
    # chunk_dates(data_df.index.min(), data_df.index.max(), interval=self.freq, as_range=True)
    data = []
    groups = np.unique(arr[:, 0])
    for _group in groups:
        group_data = arr[arr[:, 0] == _group, :]
        for _start, _end in intervals:
            # print(_start)
            _data_filter = (_start <= group_data[:, 1]) & (group_data[:, 1] < _end)
            _interval_data = group_data[_data_filter]
            _interval_agg = [_group, _start]
            _skip = len(_interval_data) == 0
            for _val, _key in [['open', 2], ['high', 3], ['low', 4], ['close', 5], ['volume', 6]]:
                # print(_key)
                _col_data = _interval_data[:, _key]
                if not _skip:
                    if _val in ['open']: _key_val = _col_data[0]
                    if _val in ['high']: _key_val = _col_data.max()
                    if _val in ['low']: _key_val = _col_data.min()
                    if _val in ['close']: _key_val = _col_data[-1]
                    if _val in ['volume']: _key_val = _col_data.sum()
                else:
                    _key_val = None
                _interval_agg.append(_key_val)
            data.append(_interval_agg)
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    timestamps = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=base)
    candles = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.DatetimeIndex(timestamps), **{_col: np.random.randint(50, 150, len(timestamps)) for _col in data_cols}})
    symbol_id = pd.DataFrame({'sid': np.random.randint(1000, 2000, symbols)})
    candles['id'] = 1
    symbol_id['id'] = 1
    data_df = symbol_id.merge(candles, on='id').drop(columns=['id'])
    print(len(data_df), "\n", data_df.head(3))

    st1 = time()
    resampled_df = pandas_resample(data_df.copy())
    print('pandas', time() - st1)

    st2 = time()
    numpy_resample(data_df.values)
    print('numpy', time() - st2)
```

Output

```
pandas 3.5319528579711914
numpy 93.10612797737122
```

Please suggest if there is any other approach or implementation which could result in better performance.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Per `sid`, all of the open/high/etc. data are the same. If this reflects reality, you need to take a very different approach to resampling. If this does not reflect reality, then your random data are being incorrectly generated and you should not broadcast them.

Comment: In reality, the open, high etc (OHLC) will be different for each timestamp per `sid`. This is just a simple example to check performance. So just copied the data for now.

Comment: Running in parallel? I tried various options to fix this, no result so far. Also, there are many unresolved `numpy` performance issues when it comes to `pandas`.

Comment: I did tried running in parallel (#4) but overhead cost beats the benefit. That is the only next best option though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that by using a [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html?highlight=grouper#pandas.Grouper) object that you use inside a [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) operation on your DataFrame, you can have a significant speedup. You can do a resample using that method at the same time you do a groupby.

Here's a comparison code:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from time import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

symbols = 1000
start = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2023, 1, 2)
data_cols = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
agg_props = {'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last', 'volume': 'sum'}
base, sample = '1min', '5min'
grouper = ['sid', pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq=sample)]

def pandas_resample(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.sort_values(['sid', 'timestamp'], inplace=True)
    df = df.set_index('timestamp')
    re_df = df.groupby('sid').resample(sample, label='left', closed='left').agg(agg_props).reset_index()
    return re_df

def pandas_resample2(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    re_df = df.groupby(grouper, as_index=False).agg(agg_props)
    return re_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    timestamps = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range(start, end, freq=base)})
    symbol_id = pd.DataFrame({'sid': np.random.randint(1000, 2000, symbols)})
    indexes = pd.merge(timestamps, symbol_id, how='cross')
    values = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, 150, size=(len(indexes), len(data_cols))), columns=data_cols)
    data_df = pd.concat([indexes, values], axis=1)
    print(len(data_df), "\n", data_df)

    data_df_resampled = data_df.copy()
    st1 = time()
    resampled_df1 = pandas_resample(data_df_resampled)
    duration_1 = time() - st1
    print('pandas 1', duration_1)
    #print(resampled_df1)

    data_df_resampled = data_df.copy()
    st2 = time()
    resampled_df2 = pandas_resample2(data_df_resampled)
    duration_2 = time() - st2
    print('pandas 2', duration_2)
    #print(resampled_df2)

    print('Are both methods equivalent?', resampled_df1.equals(resampled_df2))
    print(f'Method suggested is {duration_1/duration_2:0.2f} time faster')
```

I get around a 25 times speedup. Here is an example of the output I get on my computer:

```
1441000 
          timestamp   sid  open  high  low  close  volume
0       2023-01-01  1259    58   107  122     56     144
1       2023-01-01  1722    84   125  144     85     125
2       2023-01-01  1959    84    90  145     83     144
3       2023-01-01  1650   136   113   61     63      83
4       2023-01-01  1556    68   124   78    112     123
...            ...   ...   ...   ...  ...    ...     ...
1440995 2023-01-02  1406    87    82  121    103     123
1440996 2023-01-02  1597   110    67   70    113     120
1440997 2023-01-02  1024   131    88  149     70     136
1440998 2023-01-02  1288   136   146   72     84     129
1440999 2023-01-02  1678   118    83  134     99     148

[1441000 rows x 7 columns]
pandas 1 3.4833083152770996
pandas 2 0.13672590255737305
Are both methods equivalent? True
Method suggested is 25.48 time faster
```

What do you think?

By the way, you don't need to sort your values beforehand if you intend to do a groupby operation.

Comment: After trying several option, this is most efficient so far. Thanks a lot :)